# What is the best java RPG (Role Playing Game) engine for an experienced programmer?

Tags: java

I am looking into building a smallish Java rpg. I haven't found any good examples of a RPG engine that would be the most powerful yet most stable for an experienced Java programmer.

Any and all types. I just want to learn as much as possible about what is out there.

2d, 3d, or Isometric

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: RPG = Report Program Generator, it is a programming language. I know RPG is Role Playing Games, but should be kept separate. IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you're thinking 2d or 3d, but I played around with [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) a little a while back and found it pretty solid.